# extracting id of input from label

Tags: jquery

html

```
<label for="my_id">my label</label>
<input id="my_id" type="text" value="my value" />
```

now using label how to extract the id of input

```
$('label').text(function(){
  return $('input $(this).attr('for')').val();// like input#my_id
});
```

I think it's not correct way. How to do?

Comment: The `id` of the input is whatever the value of `for` attribute is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
$('label').text(function () {
    return $('input#' + $(this).attr('for')).val(); // like input#my_id
    //or
    return $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val(); // like #my_id 
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwcS8/2/)**

Comment: ID attribute is unique-per-page so really, no need to state it's about an `input#`

Comment: Not sure why OP wants input#my_id for.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Readability comes in, if they are doing a combined developing, Example: In future if a new developer comes in and he/she has to go through the HTML file to check what's the nature of that element, whether it is a div/span/input or something else.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I understand, but it's the `label` that does the magic. So for future development that's the element on interest. Than one might go look in the code what's happening to `label` and see the line `$('label').text(function(){` which even than does not need to have `input#` inside.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `htmlFor` property of the label to reference the text box:

```
$('label').text(function() {
   // find tag by id and return its value
   return $('#' + this.htmlFor).val();
});
```

Having read the question again, you may be looking for just this:

```
$('label').text(function() {
   return 'input#' + this.htmlFor;
});
```

See also: [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement)

Comment: +1 that's what I was trying to answer, just forgot about `htmlFor`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are forming the dynamic selector inside the receiver function is completely wrong,

Try,

```
$('label').text(function(){
  return $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val();
});
```

Or if your original HTML structure is same as the structure given, then you can use `.next()`,

```
$('label').text(function(){
  return $(this).next('input').val();
});
```

Comment: If you use `.next()` the code might break as soon one desides to slightly modify the HTML

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah sure :) That's why i just given a side note that _if your original HTML structure is same as the structure given_

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label').text(function(){
   return $('#' + $(this).prop('for')).val();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @SalmanA your PC seems broken ;) here's a DEMO of the exact code above: http://jsbin.com/rojubiro/1/edit which shows the use of the `.prop()` method

Comment: Drat, failed to notice you replaced attr with prop.

Comment: @SalmanA actually I was trying to figure out why on earth I could not use (I know it's funny) vanilla's `this.for`, seemed logic cause `for` is a reserved word so trying and failing with `attrFor` there's Jack who remembers the right way: `htmlFor` :D :D I wonder who invented that "html" prefix for relating to "attributes"...

Comment: In this case the _proper_ solution would be to use `attr('for')` or `.prop('htmlFor')`. jQuery maps `prop('for')`  to `prop('htmlFor')` and `prop('class')` to `prop('className')` behind the scenes.

Comment: @SalmanA that's not quite true and you might not be aware that jQuery `prop()` method has a wider spectrum than `.attr()` of getting browser assigned (attributes and) properties where `.attr()` might fail at, but in any case both `for` and `htmlFor` are perfectly valid (attr)properties gettable by `.prop()`.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d788010aa724f58090560e83c224d3d140814b51/src/attributes/prop.js (line 21), but anyway.

Comment: @SalmanA exactly. See? Perfectly valid. hope line 21 will not be removed in some future versions of jQ :D :D :D